# How to determine the date of the Bing imagery for an area in 2022?

Tags: bing-maps, aerial-photography, orthophoto

There was this question for 2012 (ten years ago!), but all the answers seem outdated and not working anymore: [How to determine the date of the Bing imagery for an area?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44413/how-to-determine-the-date-of-the-bing-imagery-for-an-area)

Is there any way to find the date of an orthophotography (aerial image) in 2022?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you are browsing bing.com maps. If you enable the developer tools in your browser, you can find the `x-ve-tilemeta-capturedatesrange` tag in the response headers with a tile date ranges.

Example:
https://t.ssl.ak.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/a1211200122213300102.jpeg?g=13104&n=z&prx=1

Headers:
`x-ve-tilemeta-capturedatesrange 8/18/2014-8/18/2014`

Answer (score 2):

Using the Bing Map Metadata service
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/imagery/imagery-metadata

It is possible to use **vintageEnd**    this is the latest date found in an imagery set or for **a specific imagery tile**.

[image]